# integrating history.back(-1) in php code

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I'm not a php developer and I have a basic knowledge in html.

I currently have this code

```html
<div class="page-header">
   <h1 class="<?php echo $this->item->backlink ? "backlink" : ""; ?>">
    <?php echo $this->item->backlink ? '<a class="backtomap" href="' . $this->item->backlink . '">' . JText::_('COM_FOCALPOINT_BACK_TO_MAP') . '</a>' : "";
    echo trim($this->item->title); ?>
   </h1>
  </div>
```

now I want to integrate the history.back function in place of the current

onclick="history.back(-1)"

so that the generated html looks something like

```html
<a class="backtomap" href="#" onclick="history.back(-1)>' . JText::_('COM_FOCALPOINT_BACK_TO_MAP') . '</a>'
```

I tried to change the code here and there, but without the right knowledge it doesn't really work.

Can anybody help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Change line

```
'<a class="backtomap" href="' . $this->item->backlink . '">' . JText::_('COM_FOCALPOINT_BACK_TO_MAP') . '</a>'
```

with

```
'<a class="backtomap" href="#" onclick="history.back(-1)" >' . JText::_('COM_FOCALPOINT_BACK_TO_MAP') . '</a>'
```

Comment: I thought I tried that and didn't work, but.. I was wrong. Thanks!